# Convert from string format "c(\"4\", \"5\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"10\")" to character

Tags: r, string, vector, type-conversion

How can I convert the string:

```
a <- "c(\"4\", \"5\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"10\")"
```

to a vector of values: 4,5,7,8,9,10 ?

Comment: a key question for a situation like this is "why do you have `a` in the first place"/"what are you trying to accomplish that led to `a` as an intermediate step?" there are valid cases to have such an object but they are comparatively rare 

Comment: Hi Michael, no I don't think it's avoidable and the solution works very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The not-so-likeable `eval` `parse` can be handy here

```
as.integer(eval(parse(text = a)))
#[1]  4  5  7  8  9 10
```

Or maybe you want to keep them as characters as your title indicates.

```
eval(parse(text = a))
#[1] "4"  "5"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10"
```

---

Based on how complicated the string is you could also extract all the digits from the string.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(a, "\\d+")[[1]]
```

Or in base R

```
regmatches(a, gregexpr("\\d+", a))[[1]]
```

Comment: it's in fact the perfect place for eval/parse... the ickiness part comes from "why does this string exist in the first place and was that avoidable?" 

Comment: Everyone of us has one of those eval parse answers that feels semi OK. :)